# WPF using VisualStateManager to animate panels in & out

Tags: wpf, silverlight, expression-blend, visualstatemanager

I'm hoping what I'm trying to do is possible using Visual States...

What I want to do is have a button that toggles a stackPanel between two states: 'In' and 'Out'. I would then call VisualStateManager.GoToState on the button's click event, to toggle between the two states.

[image: Panel States]

The problem I've run into is I can't figure out how to attach states to the StackPanel. It won't let me using Expression Blend. So I'm stuck... Is there anyway to animate in and out this panel using VisualStateManager? (I know I could use Storyboards and create and In and Out animation, but I'd preffer to use States if possible)

I really hope this is possible. Otherwise what is VisualStateManager good for besides doing gimmicky rollover effects on buttons?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I've also tried adding a VisualStateGroup to the LayoutRoot of the window, and then passing 'this' into the VSM in the Click event (ex: VisualStateManager.GoToState(this,"In", true)... but that doesn't work for me either.

Comment: Strange... I just put the same code into a WinPhone7 project, and it works fine... Why would it work for WinPhone7 Silverlight, but not WPF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just fired up Blend and got this:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
    x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    x:Name="Window"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="640" Height="480">

    <StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="PanelState">
                <VisualState x:Name="In"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="Out">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Margin)" Storyboard.TargetName="stackPanel">
                            <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="-65,15,0,0"/>
                        </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <ei:DataStateBehavior Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=toggleButton}" Value="True" TrueState="In" FalseState="Out"/>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <Button Content="Button" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,15,0,0">
            <TextBlock><Run Text="Funnytext"/></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
        <ToggleButton x:Name="toggleButton" Content="Toggle" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

and code behind:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var sgs=VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups(LayoutRoot);
    var sg=sgs[0] as VisualStateGroup;
    VisualStateManager.GoToElementState(LayoutRoot, ((VisualState) sg.States[sg.CurrentState == sg.States[0]?1:0]).Name,true);
}
```

(didn't know what stackpanel you meant so i just included two)

EDIT: my bad, didn't notice I didn't include the clickhandler. For for your convenience I included an example to use a Togglebutton to toggle the states...

Comment: You didn't even add an event handler to the button... what are you trying to show me? My question is, using this code you have, how would you change the state from out, to in? What parameters do you pass to the VSM in your code-behind?

Comment: Thats great. Thanks! So it seems with WPF its easiest to use GoToElementState, as opposed to GoToState since the visual state is applied to the LayoutRoot. (sorry for delay, couldn't get to it over the weekend)