# VisualStateManager.GoToState for FrameworkElement

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-3.0, frameworkelement

I have troubles animating a `StackPanel` with the `VisualStateManager`.

`VisualStateManager.GoToState()` accepts a `Control` as parameter, but `StackPanel` is of type `UIElement`/`FrameworkElement`.

How can I call `VisualStateManager.GoToState()` on a `StackPanel`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `VisualStateManager.GoToElementState`

This post might help you: [WPF using VisualStateManager to animate panels in & out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5084206/wpf-using-visualstatemanager-to-animate-panels-in-out).

**Edit:**

The methods above are only for WPF and not available in Silverlight. For Silverlight the `ExtendedVisualStateManager` from the Blend SDK might be helpful:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.expression.interactivity.core.extendedvisualstatemanager.gotoelementstate(v=expression.40).aspx

You would have to include the `Microsoft.Expression.Interactions` assembly though.

Comment: thanks again, I looked at that post, this doesnt work in wp7, the method is not defined

Comment: sorry, I don't realize. Do you use expression blend? there is the ExtendedVisualStateManager class that does seem to have the GoToElementState for silverlight.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.expression.interactivity.core.extendedvisualstatemanager.gotoelementstate(v=expression.40).aspx

Comment: in the Blend SDK for silverlight

Comment: Oh man, things are getting harder. I wouldn't find that solution by myself in less than one year ... :S